# probability of finishing at r^th game by m people

Tags: probability, recreational-mathematics, recursion

so, the question is as follows:

players $P_1,P_2...P_m$ of equal skill , play a game consecutively in pairs as $$ P_1P_2 , P_2P_3,...P_(m-1)P_m,P_mP_1,...$$

and any player who wins two consecutive games (i.e $k$ and $k+1$ game ) wins the match. if the chance that the match is won at the $r^{th}$ game is p then we need to find $p(r)$

my approach;
for small value of r I was easily able to find that $$p(1)=0/2 , p(2)=1/4, p(3)=2/8 $$ which intuitively seems that $p(r)=(r-1)/2^r$ but i can't prove it . kindly help me out.

Comment: The answer I gave below is incorrect, since it assumes that two subsequent losses for a player are a valid finish to the game, which is of course incorrect. I will remove my answer below as soon as you acknowledge this!

Comment: @jvdhooft ok go ahead. However I request you to post the correct answer(if possible). Thank you.

Comment: I have updated my answer!

Answer (score 4):

In the last two games, the second and first player must win, respectively, if the match is to end in $r \gt 1$ games. Let $g < r - 1$ be the first game that has the second player winning; then the remainder of the games $g + 1, \ldots, r - 2$ must have the second player winning as well (otherwise, the match would be finished sooner). This means that the number of valid sequences is defined by the possible values of $g$, with $g$ ranging from $0$ (no game prior to the last one has the first player win) to $r - 2$ (only game $r - 1$ has the second player win). Since each sequence is equally likely to occur, the probablity $P(r)$ of the match ending in $r$ games equals:

$$P(r) = \frac{r - 1}{2^n}$$

Comment: This conflicts with an answer to a possibly identical question, which gives the answer OP intuitively feels is correct. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4073245/players-p-1-p-2-p-m-of-equal-skill-play-a-game-consecutively-in-pairs/4074715#4074715

Comment: @trueblueanil You are right! My answer assumes that the game also ends when there are two losses of the same player in a row, but this is of course incorrect. Can we somehow notify the OP while still removing this answer?

Comment: OP is active (has asked a question today) so you can leave a comment under OP's question.