# Players $P_1,P_2...P_m$ of equal skill play a game consecutively in pairs

Tags: probability

> Players $P_1,P_2...P_m$ of equal skill play a game consecutively in pairs as $P_1P_2,P_2P_3....P_{m-1}P_m, P_mP_1$ and any player who wins two consecutive games (ie. k and (k+1)th game) wins the match. If the chance that the match is won at the rth game is $k$, then find relation between $k$ and $r$

I haven’t really understood the question or what it wants to do, so I don’t know how to begin. Can anyone explain the question and give a starter hint?

Comment: I don't quite understand the part about winning two consecutive games. Could you give an example of how that'd work?

Comment: Start with a small $m$, say $4$, and examine the probability of winning after each game: no-one can win after the first game, $P_2$ can win after the second game with probability ??, etc.

Comment: @sfs2007 I don’t understand either, which is why i asked it on MSE

Comment: @Aditya It is a math question.  For $r=2$, for example, $P_2$ must win the first two games, which has probability $2^{-2}.$  For $r=3$, the outcome of game 1 is **irrelevant**, because $r=3$ requires that $P_3$ win games 2 and 3.  So, for $r=3$, the probability is **also** $2^{-2}.$

Comment: @user2661923  Yes, my analysis was not quite correct.  I have deleted it.

Comment: @sfs2007 see my previous comment.

Comment: Do I understand that whether *P2* wins or loses the first game, the second game is between *P2* and*P3* ?

Comment: @trueblueanil The participants for each of the games are fixed in advance, as I read it (unless the match is over before a given game is reached).

Comment: @user2661923 your probability value for game 3 ignores the potential that the match already finished at game 2

Comment: @Joffan No it doesn't.  The only way for the match to end after 3 games is if $P_3$ won game 2, which prevents the match from having ended after 2 games.

Comment: So we are saying $P_1$ can never win? Then why is $P_1$ playing?

Comment: @MathLover $m$ is finite.  $P_1$ can win if there is no prior winner, and $P_1$ wins against $P_m$ and also wins the **second** encounter with $P_2$.

Comment: @user2661923 yes that is correct.

Comment: @MathLover The game is *generally* unfair, at least comparing $P_2$ versus $P_4$ versus $P_6 \cdots.$

Comment: Note;  I think the phrasing is ambiguous.  I have posted a solution below based on the notion that the match ends with the game between $P_m$ and $P_1$ even if no winner for the match is decided.  Possibly, however, we are meant to imagine that the match continues cyclically until a winner is determined.  If the latter is what whas meant, then I would look at the case of infinite $m$ but let the players recur cyclically $\pmod m$.  Thus $P_1=P_{m+1}=P_{2m+1}$ and so on.  You then just have to sum the relevant probabilities.

Answer (score 2):

Note:  what follows assumes that the match ends with the game between $P_m$ and $P_1$ even if no victor for the match is determined.  If, to the contrary, one is meant to replay the thing until a victor is set, then just use the infinite case below, setting $P_i=P_j$ if $i\equiv j\pmod m$. If you want the probability that a specified player wins, just sum the relevant probabilities.  If all you want is the probability that the match ends in a particular game, then the stated formula holds.

For simplicity, let us first consider the case where $m=\infty$ (Note that $P_1$ can never win this match).

A match can be considered a binary string, where a $0$ means that the player with the lower index won, and a $1$ means that the player with the higher index won.  Thus the match $0010$  means that the winners were $P_1,P_2,P_4, P_4$ so $P_4$ is the winner of the match.   in this way, we see that the match typically ends with the appearance of the first $10$ (player $P_1$ messes this up a little).

It is easy to count the strings with no $10$.  They must all be of the form $0^a1^b$  So there are $n+1$ such of length $n$.

The probability that a string of length $r$ has it's first $10$ ending in slot $r$ is then $$\frac {r-2+1}{2^{r-2}}\times \frac 14=\boxed {\frac {r-1}{2^r}}$$

Sanity Check:  Note that $$\sum_{r=2}^{\infty}\frac {r-1}{2^r}=1$$ so, in the case of infinite $m$, the match is eventually resolved with probability $1$.

The one exception to this analysis arises if $m$ is finite so $P_1$ might win.  In that case we need that there be no winner in the first $m-1$ games, but that $P_1$ must win the first and last.  Thus we have a word of the form $0W0$ where $W$ is a word of length $m-2$ with no $10$.  The probability of that is $$\frac 12\times \frac {m-2+1}{2^{m-2}}\times \frac 12=\frac {m-1}{2^m}$$

so the same formula holds in this case.

Sanity Check (for the exceptional case):  suppose $m=4$.  Then the paths in which $P_1$ wins are $$(P_1, P_2,P_3,P_1)\quad(P_1,P_2,P_4, P_1)\quad(P_1,P_3,P_4,P_1)$$ so the answer would be $\frac 3{16}$ in this case, matching the formula.

Remark:  there is no need for the sum of these probabilities to be $1$ since, in the finite case, the match could certainly be decided without a victor.

Comment: Is it rude if I say that I understood nothing? But seriously, what are you implying with the binary string approach? What does $0010$ have to do with $P_1,P_2,P_4,P_4$? Why was $P_4$ repeated 2 times?

Comment: I defined the map between match and string explicitly.  Game $r$ is between $P_r, P_{r+1}$.  If $P_r$ wins, mark a $0$.  If $P_{r+1}$ wins, mark a $1$.  The point is to change the problem into a familiar counting problem...convince your self that (when $m=\infty$) the match ends when you first get $10$.

Comment: All this says is that the infinite match ends the first time an upper player wins a match and then immediately wins their next match.  I find it useful to think of this as a binary string, since the equivalent counting problem is so familiar in that case.  But you can drop the analogy if you prefer.

Comment: @lulu: Happened to come to this again. Could you please clarify what you mean by ".. in the finite case, the match could certainly be decided without a victor"

Comment: @trueblueanil  reviewing what I wrote, I think the rules for the game were not stated clearly.  As I said in the first paragraph, if you assume that the game terminates with the match between $P_m$ and $P_1$, then only finitely many games are played so of course it is possible that no winner is declared under the stated rules.  However, if you imagine that the game is played cyclicly until someone wins, then the "infinite" case applies and the probability that a winner is eventually named is $1$.

Answer (score 1):

@Aditya: An attempt to simplify the presentation. We can forget about *m*, work out for $r=5$, and then generalize

The last two games *have* to be $\fbox{LW}\fbox{WL}$

and the first $(5-2)$ can either be $\fbox{WL}\fbox{WL}\fbox{WL}$ or

any  of the $3\;\fbox{WL}$ can be replaced by $\fbox{LW}$ *with the caveat that once a* $\fbox{LW}$ *has been inserted, all subsequent ones also must change to* $\fbox{LW}$

This is the rationale of $(r-2+1)$ valid strings

For this example, $Pr = \dfrac{5-2+1}{2^5}$

Putting in the general symbols, we get $Pr = \dfrac{r-1}{2^r}$

Answer (score 0):

A chart of what happens in the first few games would perhaps help supplement lulu's answer above:

[image]

Note that the outcome is split by the probabilities of the last two games, since that's how we know that the match finishes: when the "new" player wins one round and then - as the "old" player - wins the next round, shown as **NO**. Here the options for the new player winning are gathered into a single item by "forgetting" past history - so for example the **...ON** and **...NN** outcomes from game $3$ have a combined probability of $3/8$, which is then split into two $3/16$ probability outcomes of game $4$.

Answer (score 0):

The question is simply if the match ends at game $r$ who won?  If it ends on the second game, only players $1$ or $2$ could have won because they are the only players who could have played twice.  If it ends on the third game only the third player could have won.  If player $1$ wins the first game, player $3$ must win the second or the match ends at the second game.  Then the third game has to be won by player $3$ to end.  In general, if it ends at game $r$ in the first round, it is player $r$ who wins.  If the competition continues, the same is true.  Game $m$, the one between the winner of game $m-1$ and player $1$ can only be the last game if player $m$ wins it (as well as the previous).  The match is won by player $r \pmod {m}$ unless it is won in the second game, when it might be player $1$.